# Error in Lordif function when comparing questionnaires: argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I'm currently working on translating a english questionnaire to dutch. I want to test the questionnaire using DIF in R. I want to use the lordif package. I made a questionnaire of 50 observations for the english and 50 for the dutch. I have 18 questions in both the dutch and the english questionnaire. The questions have 4 options (totally disagree, disagree, agree, totally agree). I counted from 0 to 3. There is no NA in the datasets.

I used this code:

`dif <- lordif(VSsample, NLsample)`

But every time I try to run it in every single way I get this error:

> Error in if (nrow(resp.data) != length(group)) stop("nrow of resp.data
>   and length of group are non-conformable") : argument is of length zero

I checked the datasets a couple times and they are both 50 observations and 18 questions. I also tried to run the lordif code for only 1 question VS comparing it to one question NL but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how this works?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not sure whether you use `lordif()` function correctly. First argument is `resp.data` which is data frame or matrix contraning item responses, second argument is `group` which is a vactor of group designations. For more details see `?lordif`. Try to merge your data and create group membership vector.

Comment: I tried to use the merge function by making a new column with country naming it 1 for the dutch data and a new column with country for the English naming it 2. Then I tried to merge it naming it: dif_us_and_nl. I used the lordif(dif_us_and_nl, dif_us_and_nl$country) but i still get an error

Comment: You need one dataset for both dutch and english questionnaire and then you need one vector of group membership where you identify the country. Does it work?

Comment: I have 1 dataset with the dutch and the english questionnaire i called it dif_us_and_nl. Here is have 9 column (8 questions and 1 for the country with dutch = 1 and english = 2) this has 218 observations with 73 1(dutch) and 145 2(english) 2then I tried the lordif function with dif_try <- lordif(dif_us_and_nl, dif_us_and_nl$country). Here i get this error: Error in collapse(resp.data[, selection[i]], group, minCell) : 
  items must have at least two valid response categories with 5 or more cases. Do you maybe know the solution? I will be forever thankfull

Comment: try `data <- dif_us_and_nl[, 1:8]` and `group <- dif_us_and_nl[, 9]` and run `lordif(data, group)`.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much